# How to implement view with Label in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, view, toolbar

Assume that the back is using a JTextPane, and I would like to implement a view with a label. But how can I implement the view in Java? is that something like UIView on iPhone on the Java Swing? Thanks. [image]

Comment: Just add the `JTextPane` to whatever container you like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to display a `JLabel` on top of a `JTextPane`. If so, use a `JLayeredPane`.

Read the [Swing tutorial on layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) to learn how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

See [Twinkle](http://blog.swingfx.ch/twinkle-100)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about this; just pack an extra `JPanel` along the bottom of your window, and put a `JLabel` into it; set the text of the `JLabel` as needed.